# Loading custom kernel on Nexus 7

Tags: android, kernel

I am trying to build a custom kernel for my Nexus 7 (kernel version 3.1.10, android 4.1.2, rooted and unlocked), but I am running into trouble with getting the kernel to load.  I have followed all of the steps I have found online in several areas, but cannot get the kernel to load.  I suspect the problem lies somewhere in the repackaging of the kernel into boot.img.  Here are the steps I am using:

1. Download the kernel source from Google's site
2. Pull config.gz from the device, gunzip, and rename to .config in the same directory as the kernel source.

For testing purposes, I make no changes to the kernel configuration in menuconfig, etc., so the .config file is exactly the same as when it came off the device.  I have changed the extraversion in the Makefile to match the existing kernel.

Rebuild the kernel:

1. make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-

Take apart the boot.img

1. unpackbootimg -i boot.img -o unpacked
2. cat ../kernel/arch/arm/boot/zImage > unpacked/boot.img-zImage

Repack the boot.img

1. mkbootimg --kernel boot.img-zImage --ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk.gz
   --cmdline "no_console_suspend=1 console=null" --base `cat boot.img-base` -o newboot.img

Then, reboot and once in fastboot...

1. fastboot boot newboot.img

My device just hangs.  I have tried the same process on my Wifi-only Motorola Xoom, and it just boot loops.  Is there a step I'm missing?  Is there something in the ramdisk I need to change?  Thank you for your help or any insight you have.

Answer (score 1):

I hit my head against the wall with this for a few days too. Here's some tips that helped me get my kernel up and running:

1. Use split_bootimg to unpack your original boot.img. You can get it here: http://www.enck.org/tools.html
2. When running make, set SUBARCH=arm as well as ARCH
3. Be sure to use the toolchain from the android source. If you don't have it you can get it here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilt/
4. If you find yourself stuck with a looping boot animation, make sure you have the latest stable version of the kernel.

Further to the final point, I tried the commit hash method (using git log kernel to get the last commit of the prebuilt kernel) for obtaining the kernel source but found that it always hung after compilation.

In the end I opted to use the latest kernel source instead (I opted for mr1 branch), and the repacked boot.img worked first time with my 4.1.2 Android build.

Hope some of this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Jack.  I will try those things and let you know if it works.